# I read often that SCORU is superior compared to other Layer 2 solutions. But I would like to know the facts, why is that the case?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

I read often that SCORU is superior compared to other Layer 2 solutions (e.g. Arbitrum, Optimism, Polygon). But I would like to know the facts, why is that the case?

[Question from Agora](https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/media-attention-regarding-tezos-mumbai-upgrade/5211/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a comparison between Arbitrum, Optimism, and SCORUs.
[image]
[Source](https://twitter.com/mooon640/status/1639413165216743428)